# Moving object display on google maps or bing

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I want to develop an application for tracking in maps,in that i want to show moving object without reloading the whole page depending on co ordinates. Can anyone suggest me how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the information about moving objects? 
Is it a real time system or only a simulation?

In any case you can try polling server to get the new coordinates few times per second using JS, and update marker location on the map.

**EDIT**

Below you have working example of moving object **without polling** taken from google tutorial (https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/overlay-symbol-animate). What you need to change is the way of obtaining coordinates.

```
var line;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.291, 153.027),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
     mapOptions);

  var lineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(22.291, 153.027),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.291, 153.027)
  ];

  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };

  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lineCoordinates,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });

  animateCircle();
}

function animateCircle() {
    var count = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
      count = (count + 1) % 200;

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
      line.set('icons', icons);
  }, 20);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Yes coordinates are in database,stored using a web service

Comment: Then the easiest way is to pass all coordinates to your javascript and then iterate over a table and change coordinates accordingly